# Average color javascript code only in one section

Tags: javascript, html, css, average, background-color

I got a gallery grid with average color to fill the background and is working fine.

Problem 1: When I add another IMG that is not on that gallery, then the script is not working.

Problem 2: The "crossorigin="anonymous" tag is necessary too. Its possible to quit it? Or is mandatory for the script to work?

Anyone can help me with that?

(the average color script comes from [this CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jfaehrmann/pen/QWKOWzo))

```js
window.addEventListener("load", init);

function init() {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll("IMG");
  images.forEach(setBackground);
}

function setBackground(image) {
  const rgb = getAverageRGB(image);
  image.closest(
    ".image-wrapper"
  ).style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${rgb.r}, ${rgb.g}, ${rgb.b})`;
}

function getAverageRGB(image) {
  let blockSize = 500;
  let defaultRGB = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 };
  let rgb = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 };
  let imageData;

  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext("2d");

  if (!context) return defaultRGB;

  const height = (canvas.height =
    image.naturalHeight || image.offsetHeight || image.height);
  const width = (canvas.width =
    image.naturalWidth || image.offsetWidth || image.width);

  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  try {
    imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return defaultRGB;
  }

  const length = imageData.length;

  let i = 0;
  let count = 0;
  while ((i += blockSize * 4) < length) {
    ++count;
    rgb.r += imageData[i];
    rgb.g += imageData[i + 1];
    rgb.b += imageData[i + 2];
  }

  rgb.r = Math.floor(rgb.r / count);
  rgb.g = Math.floor(rgb.g / count);
  rgb.b = Math.floor(rgb.b / count);

  return rgb;
}

function imgToBase64(image) {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;

  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
li {
  margin: 10px;
}
.image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.another-picture-class {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
  <!-- PROBLEM 1: Adding another picture, not on the gallery makes the script to not work"
 
<img class="another-picture-class" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91uwocAMtSL.jpg">

-->

<ul>
   <li>
   
 <!-- PROBLEM 2: Picture without CROSSORIGIN dont work -->
 
    <picture class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91uwocAMtSL.jpg">
    </picture>
  </li>
  <li>
    <picture class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91uwocAMtSL.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" alt="some random product picture">
    </picture>
  </li>
  <li>
    <picture class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71QKQ9mwV7L.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" alt="some random product picture">
    </picture>
  </li>
  <li>
    <picture class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/417DAFJSZ9L._SX310_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" alt="some random product picture">
    </picture>
  </li>
  <li>
    <picture class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81xrBF7++0L.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" alt="some random product picture">
    </picture>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How do you add the new image, with an XHR-Request?

Comment: The crossorigin attribute is always necessary if you include an image from another domain: https://www.dofactory.com/html/img/crossorigin

Comment: Just a simple image, you can see it in the snippet (its hide in a comment) !

Comment: "*Just a simple image, you can see it in the snippet*": if you write the new image into the html file, then you have to save/upload (depends on local or remote developing) and refresh the browser page in order to make the javascript rerun to calculate the backgrounds.